# How can I add a custom tag in MediaWiki templates for my extension to process?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I want to add 3 custom tags which a MediaWiki admin will add to her templates(for example to the Userlogin.php template for the login page), and these extensions need to be processed by the extension I am building. The tags will be of the form `<mytag_forXaction>`, `<mytag_forYaction>`. When the extensions parses through this, they will be replaced with valid HTML tags to display boxes or images or whatever the desired purpose may be.

So far, I have tried doing this:

```
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    die( 'This file is a MediaWiki extension, it is not a valid entry point' );
}

$wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(
   'path' => __FILE__,
   'name' => 'Test Parser Function',
   'description' => 'A simple example parser function extension',
   'version' => 0.1,
   'author' => 'Me',
   'url' => 'https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions',
);

$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'buttonParserSetup';
function buttonParserSetup( ) {
    global $wgParser;

    //apploginbtn will be the tag to be replaced
    $wgParser->setHook( 'apploginbtn', 'RenderAppLoginButton' );

    return true; // Return true so that MediaWiki continues to load extensions.
}

// Render the output of the parser function.
function RenderAppLoginButton( $input, $argv ) {
    $output = "SUCCESSFULLY REPLACED.";
    return $output;
}
```

So now when I add the tag <apploginbtn />, or <apploginbtn></apploginbtn>, or {{apploginbtn}}, or {{#apploginbtn}} to the Userlogin.php file at the desired position, the tag doesn't get replaced.

Any help in achieving the desired outcome will be a lot helpful as am stuck with this since 2-3 days and the documentation isn't helpful at all.

Also, am using MediaWiki 1.9.3 as that's the lowest version I need to start supporting.

Comment: You are placing them where? The system message which is shown at Special:Login, or really in the `Userlogin.php` source file?

Comment: In the Userlogin.php file. Where should I be placing them? I want to precisely position them in the layout.

Comment: Somehow all the download links lead to a 404 page[http://upload.wikimedia.org/ext-dist/Persona-master-b7d4117.tar.gz]. I guess MediaWiki isn't maintaining or archiving these extensions. If you can elaborate a little more, in an answer maybe then I can pick up hints am sure. For example if you could name the hooks that would be useful, as I have used a couple of them but to no avail.

Comment: Ok, I'm using the BeforePageDisplay hook. I guess I will have to parse through the HTML to find the tag I'm looking for. Only question now is, am I bypassing any security check in doing so?

Comment: What security check do you think of?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`UserLoginForm` hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/UserLoginForm). It calls your extension function with the [`UserLogin` template](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=includes/templates/Userlogin.php) ([at SVN](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/Userlogin_8php_source.html)) which is used to create the login form. It is an instance of [QuickTemplate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aQuickTemplate), and you will be able to edit / stuff it up from your extension code.

Do not try to build a parser extension (tag extension) if you don't target parsed wikitext.

Comment: I tried following the UserLoginForm hook with all the links you provided for a day, but to no help. And I don't even know what type of extension I want and what I absolutely do not want. All I want to do is place some HTML in a page upon discovering a pre-decided tag. If you can cite some example pseudo code to achieve what I want as I really can't get this to work. Also, what's a tag extension? Is working with wiki-formatted text a tag extension, or introducing new xml-style tags a tag extension?

Comment: Yes, a [tag extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Tag_extension) introduces new xml-style *extension* tags for wikitext.

"place some html upon discovering a tag": At which parse/output step would you like to discover the tag (or: a which place would the tag be placed) and who places it there?

Comment: I really am open to the tag getting parsed at any stage, as long as the site owner can precisely place the tag to have the buttons and links how up at the right places. Editing the parsed messages doesn't provide that much control.

Comment: I think a configuration object for your extension code would be the best choice.